# Rails3: How to insert a value to a column without user interaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have post and user model and I have  Many(*posts*) to One(*User*) association.
I want to display only the posts which are created by that user(current user).
So somehow I have to inject the currently logged in user's id into the "user_id" foreign key
of the post model during creation. I'm using Devise as my authentication system.
Any solutions of how to achieve this ?
I'm using Rails version 3.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With devise simply use the "current_user" helper ;)

```
<% if user_signed_in? %> 
  <% current_user.posts.each do |post| %> 
    <%= post.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: He cannot do this yet because the Post models don't know which user has made them.

Answer (score 0):

In your `PostsController#create` method, you can set the `Post`'s `user` to the `current_user` (since you are using Devise).

```
def create
  @post = Post.create(params[:post]) do |p|
    p.user = current_user
  end
  #respond_with(@post) or Rails 2 equivalent
end
```